# Does the order of the word 'please' matter?

Tags: word-order

Is there a difference between:

> Can I go home, please?

and

> Can I, please, go home?

I feel like the first is more formal, when the second shows some kind of irritation. Am I right?

Comment: Or indeed *"**Please** can I go home?"* I think it mainly depends on context and spoken delivery/stress. Anything else is just subjective supposition.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could probably be better asked on ELL. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re on the right lines. *Can I go home, please?* is the normal order. Depending on how the words are stressed, *Can I, please, go home?* might give more of a pleading tone.